# Efficiently extracting columns/regex on a large file

Tags: regex, awk

I need to pull some information out of a file I have. I had been doing it in R previously, but the file is very, very big, and it's taking quite a while, so I feel like using command line tools is a much better alternative.

The file basically consists of 100 tab-delimited columns, I'm only interested in the 1st, 2nd and 4th columns however.

An example of the first four columns in the file:

```
10  rs149353603:74656:C:G   0   74656   ...
10  rs140638708:75794:G:T   0   75794   ...
10  rs201043140:76210:A:G   0   76210   ...
10  rs202007578:76294:T:C   0   76294   ...
10  rs75914453  0   77582   ...
```

I would like it to be in the format 2nd column, 1st column, 4th column. Furthermore, I'd like to trim off everything but the first rs# in the cases where the second row has a colon in it (everything before the first colon).

E.g. the first line would be

```
rs149353603 10  74656
```

I fully intend to learn awk when I have the time, but that time is not now unfortunately! Could anyone lend a hand here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk command like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {sub(/:.*$/, "", $2); print $2, $1, $4}' file
rs149353603 10  74656
rs140638708 10  75794
rs201043140 10  76210
rs202007578 10  76294
rs75914453  10  77582
```

Comment: Doesn't work for the (slightly) more complex case shown in the last line of the input.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It is fixed now, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Since your file is very large, you might find that using "cut" first is faster, along the lines of the following pipeline:

```
cut -f 1,2,4 | awk ....
```